# Spikes or glitches in Modelsim

Tags: vhdl, simulation, modelsim, waveform

I've been learning VHDL for a while and I'm making a project right now. I made a NCO (Numerically controlled Oscillator) and a cordic algorithm to produce sine and cosine with a certain frequency.
I don't know why I get spikes on my waves in Modelsim. I guess they are caused by the case statement when it changes the quadrant for the cordic algorithm to work with angles between -180 and +180.
I've read that it could be a "normal" behavior of Modelsim because of the iterations of the simulator (VHDL delta cycles). But I don't know how and if I should fix them.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY phase_accumulator_module IS
    GENERIC (
                LGTBL: INTEGER := 16; --lunghezza table log base 2
                W: INTEGER := 32; 
                OW: INTEGER := 16 
                    );

    PORT (
                clk: IN STD_LOGIC;
                reset: IN STD_LOGIC;
                i_dphase: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(W-1 DOWNTO 0);
                o_val: BUFFER STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(W-1 DOWNTO 0);
                o_val_test:BUFFER STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(OW-1 DOWNTO 0);
                o_val_laser: BUFFER STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(W-1 DOWNTO 0);
                quadrant: BUFFER STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0)
                );
END phase_accumulator_module;

ARCHITECTURE behave OF phase_accumulator_module IS
SIGNAL r_step,r_step_laser,r_step_test: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(W-1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
SIGNAL r_phase,r_phase_laser,r_phase_test: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(W-1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
SIGNAL r_phase_pipe,r_phase_laser_pipe: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(W-1 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
CONSTANT P: INTEGER := LGTBL;
BEGIN 
    R_Step_pro: PROCESS(clk,reset)
    BEGIN
        IF(reset='1') THEN
            r_step <= (OTHERS=>'0');
            r_step_test <= (OTHERS=>'0');
            r_step_laser <= (OTHERS=>'0');
            ELSE IF(rising_edge(clk)) THEN
                r_step <= i_dphase; -- 2^W*f/fs
                r_step_test <= i_dphase; --test signal
                r_step_laser <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SHIFT_RIGHT(UNSIGNED(i_dphase),1));
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS R_Step_pro;
    
    R_phase_pro: PROCESS(clk,reset)
    BEGIN
        IF(reset='1') THEN
            r_phase <= (OTHERS=>'0');
            r_phase_test <= (OTHERS=>'0');
            r_phase_laser <= (OTHERS=>'0');
            o_val <= (OTHERS=>'0');
            o_val_test <= (OTHERS=>'0');
            o_val_laser <= (OTHERS=>'0');
            ELSE IF(rising_edge(clk)) THEN
                r_phase <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(UNSIGNED(r_phase) + UNSIGNED(r_step));
                r_phase_test <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(UNSIGNED(r_phase_test) + UNSIGNED(r_step_test)); --test signal
                r_phase_laser <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(UNSIGNED(r_phase_laser) + UNSIGNED(r_step_laser));
                quadrant <= r_phase(W-1 DOWNTO w-2);
                CASE quadrant IS
                    WHEN "00" | "11" =>
                        r_phase_pipe <= r_phase;
                        r_phase_laser_pipe <= r_phase_laser;
                    WHEN "01" =>
                        r_phase_pipe <= "00" & r_phase(W-3 DOWNTO 0);
                        r_phase_laser_pipe <= "00" & r_phase_laser(W-3 DOWNTO 0);
                    WHEN "10" =>
                        r_phase_pipe <= "11" & r_phase(W-3 DOWNTO 0);
                        r_phase_laser_pipe <= "11" & r_phase_laser(W-3 DOWNTO 0);
                    WHEN OTHERS =>
                        null;
                END CASE;
                o_val_test <= r_phase_test(W-1 DOWNTO W-P);
                o_val <= r_phase_pipe;
                o_val_laser <= r_phase_laser_pipe;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS R_phase_pro;
END behave;
```

This is the cordic algotithm vhdl file:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY signal_gen_cordic_module IS
    GENERIC (   
                bits: INTEGER := 16;
                bits_out_c: INTEGER := 32;
                iter : INTEGER := 32
                    );
    PORT (
            clk: IN STD_LOGIC;
            reset: IN STD_LOGIC;
            locked: IN STD_LOGIC;
            z0: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (bits_out_c-1 DOWNTO 0);
            quadrant: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
            sine,cosine: BUFFER STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(bits-1 DOWNTO 0)
                );
END signal_gen_cordic_module;

ARCHITECTURE behave OF signal_gen_cordic_module IS
    TYPE temp IS ARRAY (0 TO iter-1) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(bits_out_c-1 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL x_temp,y_temp,z_temp:  temp;
    CONSTANT x0: SIGNED(bits_out_c-1 DOWNTO 0) := "00000000000000000010111100011010"; --0.6072*2^16
    CONSTANT y0: SIGNED(bits_out_c-1 DOWNTO 0) := "00000000000000000000000000000000";

    SIGNAL x00,y00: SIGNED(bits_out_c-1 DOWNTO 0);
    
    TYPE atand IS ARRAY (0 TO iter-1) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(bits_out_c-1 DOWNTO 0);
    CONSTANT arctan: atand :=
        (
x"20000000",
x"12E4051E",
x"09FB385B",
x"051111D4",
x"028B0D43",
x"0145D7E1",
x"00A2F61E",
x"00517C55",
x"0028BE53",
x"00145F2F",
x"000A2F98",
x"000517CC",
x"00028BE6",
x"000145F3",
x"0000A2FA",
x"0000517D",
x"000028BE",
x"0000145F",
x"00000A30",
x"00000518",
x"0000028C",
x"00000146",
x"000000A3",
x"00000051",
x"00000029",
x"00000014",
x"0000000A",
x"00000005",
x"00000003",
x"00000001",
x"00000001",
x"00000000"
            );
            

BEGIN 
    PROCESS(clk,reset)
        BEGIN
            IF(reset='1') THEN
                cosine <= (OTHERS=>'0');
                sine <= (OTHERS=>'0');
                FOR i IN iter-1 DOWNTO 0 LOOP
                   x_temp(i) <= (OTHERS=>'0');
                   y_temp(i) <= (OTHERS=>'0');
                   z_temp(i) <= (OTHERS=>'0');
                END LOOP;
                ELSE IF(rising_edge(clk)) THEN
                    IF(locked='1') THEN
                        IF(quadrant="00" OR quadrant="11") THEN
                            x00 <= x0;
                            y00 <= y0;
                            ELSE IF(quadrant="01") THEN
                                x00 <= -y0;
                                y00 <= x0;
                                ELSE
                                    x00 <= y0;
                                    y00 <= -x0; 
                            END IF;
                        END IF;
                    x_temp(0) <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(x00);
                    y_temp(0) <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(y00);
                    z_temp(0) <= z0;
                        FOR i IN 0 TO iter-2 LOOP
                            IF(z_temp(i)(z0'HIGH)='1') THEN
                                x_temp(i+1) <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SIGNED(x_temp(i)) + SHIFT_RIGHT(SIGNED(y_temp(i)),i));
                                y_temp(i+1) <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SIGNED(y_temp(i)) - SHIFT_RIGHT(SIGNED(x_temp(i)),i));
                                z_temp(i+1) <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SIGNED(z_temp(i)) + SIGNED(arctan(i)));
                                ELSE
                                    x_temp(i+1) <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SIGNED(x_temp(i)) - SHIFT_RIGHT(SIGNED(y_temp(i)),i));
                                    y_temp(i+1) <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SIGNED(y_temp(i)) + SHIFT_RIGHT(SIGNED(x_temp(i)),i));
                                    z_temp(i+1) <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SIGNED(z_temp(i)) - SIGNED(arctan(i)));
                            END IF;
                        END LOOP;
                            cosine <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(RESIZE(SIGNED(x_temp(iter-1)),bits));
                            sine <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(RESIZE(SIGNED(y_temp(iter-1)),bits));
                    END IF;
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END PROCESS;
END behave;
```

[image]

My modelsim version is 10.5b. Thank you for any help! :)

Comment: The problem can't be replicated without a [mcve] here a testbench driving the model and hierarchy top level tying your shown code together. There are no outliers in the arctan table which leaves quadrature issues or math errors. By using internal signals in waveforms you can troubleshoot the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you mean with outliers in the arctan table?

Comment: There's no glitches in the numbers.

Comment: Oh ok. I know that. The problem lies on the case statement but I don't know how to fix it. 
I've use already the vectoring cordic algorithm succesfully.

Comment: Provide a [mcve], there isn't enough info in the waveform.

Comment: Since some of them are at -ve peaks, pay careful attention to signal levels and arithmetic overflow. Also zoom in on the time display and note their duration : 1 delta cycle? or 1 clock cycle? 1 clock cycle you DEFINITELY need to fix.